# how to group a multidimensional array using a condition in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array

```
   Array
 (
   [0] => Array
        (
        [shop] => 3
        [price] => 332.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [shop] => 1
        [price] => 3335.00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [shop] => 3
        [price] => 235.00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [shop] => 1
        [price] => 402.50
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [shop] => 3
        [price] => 332.00
    )



)
```

I need to group using `shop` and get get the minimum `price` of each shop in the array.

The expected result is as follows

```
     Array
 (
   [0] => Array
        (
        [shop] => 3
        [price] => 235.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [shop] => 1
        [price] => 402.50
    )
)
```

How will I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use additional variable

```
<?php
$arr = Array
(
    0 => Array
    (
        'shop' => 3,
        'price' => 332.00
    ),
    1 => Array
    (
        'shop' => 3,
        'price' => 232.00
    ),
    2 => Array
    (
        'shop' => 1,
        'price' => 232.00
    ),
    3 => Array
    (
        'shop' => 3,
        'price' => 432.00
    ),
    4 => Array
    (
        'shop' => 1,
        'price' => 132.00
    ),


);
$filtered = array();
foreach($arr as $prices){
    if(FALSE === isset($filtered[$prices['shop']]) || $filtered[$prices['shop']]['price'] > $prices['price']){
        $filtered[$prices['shop']] = $prices;
    }
}

$filtered = array_values($filtered);
print_r($filtered);
```

This is very fast example how you can achieve this

Comment: @Yes it is fast for 4 elements :) and that's a good answer..But Consider using database for bigger data..

Comment: I think Adrian was talking about time of my answer:) But I agree that this should be done on DB level

Comment: @RadekAdamiec Time of your answer it is :)

Comment: @ern this function will be handing only small arrays as of now,so i dont think speed will be a big issue here.

Comment: Thats what every developer says :D "I don't  need this to be fast it will handle small data" and few month later you curse the day you made this decision :P

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple.
Create a new array where you will host your stores as keys, and prices as values. What you want to do is to go through each element and first if the key does not exists in your new array, add it and its value. If however the key already exists, check if the current value is lower, and save it if true.

```
    $grouped = [];
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        foreach ($k as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($grouped[$key])) {
                if ($value < $grouped[$key]) {
                    $grouped[$key] = $value;
                }
            } else {
                $grouped[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Your new array will look like this (store => price):

```
    [
        1 => 402.50,
        3 => 235.00
    ]
```