# Reduce an array in PHP to get the lowest value

Tags: php, arrays

Supposing I have this array in PHP:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => Yellow
            [name] => Banana
            [quantity] => 124
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [color] => Red
            [name] => Cherry
            [quantity] => 24
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [color] => Yellow
            [name] => Apple
            [quantity] => 224
        )

)
```

How can I reduce this array if :

- `color` is yellow and
- `quantity` is the lowest

So from the example above, I should have only this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => Yellow
            [name] => Banana
            [quantity] => 124
        )    
)
```

What I have tried so far:

```
$min = array_reduce($array, function($min, $details) {
  return min($min, $details['quantity']);
}, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: What was the result of what you tried?  For clarity, you want to filter the array by color before reducing it?

Comment: @Devon it can be done in this way if it's working. My previous code was return me only the `min value`.

Comment: This technique is related: [how to group a multidimensional array using a condition in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35104948/2943403)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a simple loop like this, because it's readable and easy to understand what is happening.

```
foreach($array as $arr) {
    if($arr['color'] == 'Yellow') {
        if(!isset($min) || $min['quantity'] > $arr['quantity']) {
            $min = $arr;
        }   
    }
}

print_r($min);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [color] => Yellow
    [name] => Banana
    [quantity] => 124
)
```

---

If you want `$min` to still be an array like your example output, you can just add it to an array like this.

```
if(isset($min)) $min = [$min];
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [color] => Yellow
            [name] => Banana
            [quantity] => 124
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution.

This solution takes into consideration what has already been created by the applicant, completing the code to obtain the required result.

```
$filtered = array_filter ($array, fn ($v) =>  $v['color'] == 'Yellow');
$min = array_reduce($filtered, fn ($minVal, $v) => min($minVal, $v['quantity']), PHP_INT_MAX);
$filtered = array_filter ($filtered, fn ($v) => $v['quantity'] == $min);

print_r ($filtered);
```

The first array_filter selects all rows that have color = 'Yellow', decreasing the dataset to process.

With array_reduce we find the smallest value of quantity, like @F_M did, but on a smaller dataset.

Finally with another array_filter we are going to extract the row with the value just found.

Comment: This is executing too many loops.  This can be done in 1 pass instead of 3.  This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: @mickmackusa  thanks for your opinion.
Anyway, 'too many loops', is an arbitrary statement.
This solution is perhaps not-the-best-in-the-world but it comes closest to the *asker's approach*. No particular algorithms are used, therefore it is sufficient to look for the functions used in the PHP manual (www.php.net) and an explanation of this would have seemed pedantic :-)

Comment: My statement is made non-arbitrary in the following sentence.  This task can be accomplished in a single loop over the data.  If someone who doesn't understand how to do this task is coming to Stack Overflow to learn, then the simplicity of the functionality is moot -- they  need to understand what a snippet does / how it works.  It won't take much time to improve this answer.  You might even explain how your answer accommodates the possibility of multiple lowest datasets -- which differs from some other advice on this page.  Adding explanations improves searchability too.

Comment: @mickmackusa I appreciate your exaustive explanation. Regarding the judgment on too many loops, however, I do not agree: the solutions adopted must always take account of efficiency, ease of reading, ease of maintenance and also of the context.
For example I usually prefer to use a loop or a search in a list (array) instead of setting a complex 'if ': efficiency decreases but readability and ease of maintenance increase and the balance remains positive. But everything also depends on the amount of data to be processed.
I'll follow your advice regarding adding explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a more versatile, generic function that could be modified to suit other similar scenarios where the input array does not necessarily contain the keys/values cited in the question.

```
$src=array(
    array(
        'colour'=>'Red',
        'name'=>'raspberry',
        'qty'=>524
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'yellow',
        'name'=>'Banana',
        'qty'=>124
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'green',
        'name'=>'gooseberry',
        'qty'=>23
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'Red',
        'name'=>'Cherry',
        'qty'=>24
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'green',
        'name'=>'cucumber',
        'qty'=>457
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'yellow',
        'name'=>'Banana',
        'qty'=>225
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'purple',
        'name'=>'Plum',
        'qty'=>40
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'Red',
        'name'=>'strawberry',
        'qty'=>1245
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'green',
        'name'=>'lime',
        'qty'=>44520
    ),
    array(
        'colour'=>'yellow',
        'name'=>'mango',
        'qty'=>6225
    )
);

# criteria to apply to the filter
$key='colour';
$value='yellow';
$column='qty';
$dir='low';



function filter( $input, $key, $value, $column, $dir='low' ){
    # filter the array by matching desired field to desired value, ignoring case.
    $filtered=array_filter( $input, function( $item ) use( $key, $value ){
        return is_array( $item ) && strtolower( $item[ $key ] )==strtolower( $value );
    });
    
    # determine the sort order for the filtered results.
    $sort=$dir=='low' ? SORT_ASC : SORT_DESC;
    
    # find the columns by which final output is derived.
    $cols=array_column( $filtered, $column );
    
    # sort the columns.
    array_multisort( $cols, $sort, $filtered );
    
    # return the first item from filtered & now sorted data.
    return array_shift( $filtered );
}

# run the filter
$result=filter( $src, $key, $value, $column, $dir );


printf(
    '<pre>%s</pre>', 
    print_r( is_null( $result ) ? 'No results' : $result, true )
);
```

The above yields:

```
Array
(
    [colour] => yellow
    [name] => Banana
    [qty] => 124
)
```

If the criteria change and you need the highest rather than lowest that can be quickly realised by modifying the `$dir` variable.

Comment: It is not necessary to sort the the entire filtered payload -- only to extract the qualifying data with the lowest column value.  What if there is a tie for the min value?  This only returns 1 row, right?